# Select CSS Element Outside of Parent Element

Tags: html, css

I want to select CSS element that are outside of the parent selector. Can I do that with just CSS? Below are the example that I want to achieve:

```
<p>Register Form</p>
<div>
  <p>Full Name :</p>
  <p><input type='text' name='name' required></p>
</div>
<p>Please fill in the box above</p>
```

I want make the `<p>` after the `div` to be hidden if the input type is not empty. Below are the `style` that I have tried but with failed result:

```
<style>
div > p input:required:valid + p {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I recommend you can expand your parent selector scope with for example... SASS, you can read more about this using the & selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly this can't be done with pure css. You can't modify parents of elements with css, only children and subsequent siblings.

You could have javascript toggle a class on the parent div when its child input is valid/invalid, and then use CSS to modify the parent div's sibling.

Comment: Thank you for the idea @RoseRobertson

Comment: @Amran - Any reason you can't keep the input and instruction on the same level? Why not just make them siblings? [It works fine](https://jsbin.com/bumizu/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @misterManSam, actually that validation is for a textarea and I'm using [Bootstrap-Markdown](http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/) on the textarea.